# Can a variables type be implied from a seperate function result in typescript?

Tags: typescript, variables, types

Say you have this simplified example:

```
type ApiResponse = {finished: false} | {finished: true, response: number}

function bothRequestsComplete(
  request1: ApiResponse,
  request2: ApiResponse
): boolean {
  // Return true if both of the requests are finsihed
  return request1.finished && request2.finished
}

function makeRequest(): ApiResponse {
  return {finished: true, response: Math.random()}
}

const foo = makeRequest(); 
const bar = makeRequest();

if (bothRequestsComplete(foo, bar)) {
  console.log(foo.response + bar.response)
}
```

Currently this is invalid typescript because typescript doesn't know that in theory, `foo` and `bar` will both have `response`. Is there anyway to imply to typescript that `foo` and `bar`s response will be a valid number after the `bothRequestsComplete` function returns true?

I could wrap the `console.log(foo.response + bar.response)` with a `if (foo.finished && bar.finished)`, but that defeats the purpose of the function.

(besides ignoring them)

Comment: What if you do `delete foo.response`? It's valid because foo's type is `ApiResponse`, so it makes sense TypeScript doesn't assume `response` exists on it

Comment: Not sure how that'd be useful, then I wouldn't be able to use the response meaningfully. `foo` will always have a `response` after `bothRequestsComplete` so we should be able to tell typescript that.

Comment: My bad, it's not possible to call `delete foo.response`. However, TypeScript doesn't look inside the logic of your `bothRequestsComplete` function, so it doesn't *know* that you're checking both responses are of the right type. If you take the logic out of the function, it works as expected. You could do that or maybe use [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)